# Surface plot where the coloring depends on the radius or distance from a point instead of one coordinate

Tags: pgfplots, 3d, polar

I would like to know if there is a possibility to create a 3d surface plot where the colorbar depends not on one coordinate but rather on the distance from origin (radius in polar coordinates).

I found several examples where i can create a surface plot for a 3d object where the colorbars behaviour depends on the x or y or z coordinate like this one:
(Here it depends on the z- coordinate)

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{width=7cm,compat=1.18}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[view={60}{45}]
    \addplot3 [
        surf,
        no marks,
        z buffer=sort,
        samples=30,domain=-1:1,y domain=0:2*pi,
    ] (
{sqrt(1-x^2) * cos(deg(y))},
{sqrt( 1-x^2 ) * sin(deg(y))},
x*0.5
);
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Finaly i would like to create a plot like this (which was created with python):

[image: Surface plot from python]

Is someone out there how knows how to color this plot with a dependence on the radius instead of z-coordinate ? Thanks a lot!

Comment: You can probably use [`point meta`](https://tikz.dev/pgfplots/reference-meta), but you should maybe provide a MWE that better shows what you try to do. How would you calculate the radius (to be exact the value to set the color) in the above example? How should the output look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[line join=round]
\begin{axis}[axis equal]
\addplot3[
surf, z buffer=sort,
domain=0:2*pi, samples=60, variable=t,
y domain=0:pi, samples y=60, variable y=p,
point meta=sqrt(x^2+y^2+z^2),
trig format=rad,
] ({sin(t)*(cos(p)+exp(-(40*(p-pi/4)^2)))},{sin(t)*(sin(p)+exp(-(20*(p-pi/2)^2)))},{cos(t)});
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Blue red and yellow sphere with ridges]

Comment: Thank you very much for your suggestion! This is exactly what I was looking for.